# How to remove a blank page after maketitle, scrbook

Tags: titles, blank-page, scrbook

There appears a blank page between the title page and the table of content. Many had this problem, but no solution works for me, because no one used the `scrbook` class.

```
\documentclass[DIV=10,openany]{scrbook}

\title{Documentation}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontent

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user41082".

Answer (score 5):

Before I provide a solution, I want to quote the KOMA manual.

> With the standard classes, the back of the title page of a double-side
>   print is left empty. **However, with KOMA-Script the back of the full
>   title page can be used for other information.** Exactly two elements
>   which the user can freely format are recognized: titlebackhead and
>   titlebackfoot . The head can reach up to the foot and vice versa. If
>   one takes this manual as an example, the exclusion of liability was
>   set with the help of the `\uppertitleback` command.

<sub>Scrguien page 60</sub>

So the blank page is related to the information provided by ￼`\uppertitleback{}` and `\lowertitleback{}`. There is no way to suppress this by options if you use the standard `maketitle` definition.￼

You  can do the following:

1. Use the option `titlepage=false`. In this way the environment `titlepage` isn't used and all elements are part of the text.
2. Use either ￼`\uppertitleback{}` or `\lowertitleback{}`. So you need the extra page.
3. Redefine the default command `\maketitle` (see below)
4. Use an alternative titlepage (German): http://komascript.de/titlepage

ad 3:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\if@twoside\next@tpage}{\iffalse}{}{}
\makeatother
```